# How do html fonts visible in pdf mode?

Tags: html, css

```css
 @import url(myfont.ttf);
  header h4{font-size: 20px;position: relative;top: 18px;left: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;margin: 5px;}
        header h5{font-size: 25px;font-family:alice_0;}
```

My font is properly working on browser but not working in pdf format. I am not able to fix this.

```html
 <h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px;font-family:alice_0;">LAO PEOPLE'S DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC</h4>
              
             <h5 style="font-family:alice_0;">Lao People's Democratic Republic</h5>
```

Here you can see the image, I have given the image link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiQmg.jpg

I am converting my html to pdf through this link:

https://laomarad.la/test-pdf/

Comment: We need to see how you are converting to pdf. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How are you setting the font face? How are you converting to pdf?

Comment: You have to use PDF writer library and manually add font files to that library

Comment: If you need to use that link to convert to pdf then you need to contact whoever provided that code to see how to add your chosen fonts. I note the name of the link includes the word 'test'. As an aside, have you tried converting to pdf using print to see what happens?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying custom text the font must be available to the device that is doing the rendering. So I have installed Alice0_Lao and can use that along with other fonts in my HTML, and since its in my device it will also be available for PDF production.

[image]

You say:-

> I am converting my html to pdf through this link:
> https://laomarad.la/test-pdf/

***However when using a web service that server may or may not have the font.*** so my example also will not work on that site.

[image]